# Passing array as argument to std::thread

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, c++11

I'm having difficulty passing an array of integers to a function using `std::thread`. It seems like thread doesn't like the array portion of it. What other way is there to pass an array to a threaded function?

```
#include <thread>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

void process(int start_holder[], int size){
  for (int t = 0; t < size; t++){
   cout << start_holder[t] << "\n";
  }
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  int size = 5;
  int holder_list[size] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
  std::thread run_thread(process,holder_list,size); 
  //std::ref(list) doesnt work either
  //nor does converting the list to std::string then passing by std::ref
  run_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use standard library names for your variables, don't say `using namespace std;`. In fact, don't say it anyway.

Comment: Is this actually a problem with `std::thread`, or is it `int list[size] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};`, which doesn't work with Clang despite the VLA extension?

Comment: ok, any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: i think it's a problem with std::thread. should i use pthread instead and put the array in a struct?

Comment: Change `size`'s type to `const int`.

Comment: I don't know about your compiler, but it [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c32bed3bcedd7426) when slightly modifying the aforementioned line. It's really hard to tell whether it's the same problem you have when there's no error message in the question and the code has some other errors besides that one (like `holder` being used instead of `start_holder`).

Comment: no luck brian, wont compile. getting the same error: " variable-sized array type ‘const int (&)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)size) + -1)) + 1)]’ is not a valid template argument
 std::thread run_thread(process,list,size);"

Comment: chris, the function itself isn't what's important, it's passing the array to the function that im interested in.

Comment: chris, maybe it is compiler. what are you using for compiler? i have -std=c++0x

Comment: @MartinForde, [Clang 3.7.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6292cc8c8ffd3f2). It [also works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ef04e0af350eb45) with [GCC 5.2.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e661c03a50f0c1d6). Wandbox is a good site if you want to fiddle around with many versions and find the tipping point.

Comment: Array is spelled `std::array` in C++, or `std::vector` if you don't know the size beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++ start using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead of the c-style arrays. There are many other [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) types as well. If you want a fixed size array use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead (since C++11).

These containers have functions to get the size so you do not need to send it through as a separate argument.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void process(std::vector<int> start_holder){
    for(int t = 0; t < start_holder.size(); t++){
       std::cout << start_holder[t] << "\n";
    }
    // Or the range based for
    for(int t: start_holder) {
       std::cout << t << "\n";
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::vector<int> holder_list{ 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
    std::thread run_thread(process, holder_list); 
    run_thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `size` constant:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void process(int* start_holder, int size){
  for (int t = 0; t < size; t++){
   std::cout << start_holder[t] << "\n";
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  static const int size = 5;
  int holder_list[size] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
  std::thread run_thread(process, holder_list, size); 
  run_thread.join();
}
```

If `size` is variable, `int arr[size]` is not a standard C++. It is a *variable array* extension to the language as your compiler says in the error and is not compatible with `int*` aka `int []`.